# POSIX sh: how do compound commands work with pipes?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, posix

I'm trying to understand how groups of sequential commands (named "lists" in GNU bash manual) work with pipes in POSIX sh definition or its implementations. For example, the following code:

```
if test-expr1; then
  cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; ...
fi | { cmd4; cmd5; ...; } | cmd6
```

Here, the pipeline has two sequential "lists" and a single command, where `cmd2` executes after `cmd1` finishes and `cmd5` after `cmd4`. However, all three are run in parallel so the pipeline doesn't block.

My first guess was that for each of these "lists", a subshell is created, with a separate PID, which executes all commands in sequence, but doesn't block the shell from spawning other processes — which would happen if shell started waiting for `cmd1` to complete. This was incorrect, though, as `echo $$` still reports the same PID even in piped command lists.

The question is: how exactly are fork()/waitpid() used to achieve the correct behavior?

Comment: For `{ list; }` no subshell is created. For `( list )` a subshell is created: [Command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html)

Comment: Wrt *This was incorrect, though, as echo $$ still reports the same PID*, no, you're wrong. The value of **$** doesn't change in subshells.

Comment: @oguzismail — Oh, I see, thanks. Still, even with `$PPID` I get the same result

Comment: Aaand now try `BASHPID` :p

Comment: Despite garnering a couple upvotes immediately, this question is not reasonably scoped. There are numerous implementations of POSIX sh developed for various operating systems, how is it possible to explain how each shell implements pipelines in a single answer?

Comment: @oguzismail is your comment itself not a reasonable answer to a reasonable question?  It seems to me that the question itself is quite well-scoped, it just turns out that the _answer_ is that there's no well-defined behavior here.

Comment: @oguzismail — sorry if I was unclear in my question. I intended to ask about some possible implemenations of this behavior

Comment: I get it, but still, I don't understand what kind of an answer is expected here. Like, it's the subshell that waits for `cmd1` to complete, not the parent. And a pipeline indeed blocks the parent shell unless started at the background. Other than such corrections to your predictions I don't see what else can be provided in an answer to this question. The whole question seems to be based on a chain of misunderstandings to me.

Comment: Have you tried tracing execution with `set -x` or examined output generated by a syscall tracing tool such as `strace` or `truss`?  That should give you some idea of what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if test-expr1; then
  cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; ...
fi | { cmd4; cmd5; ...; } | cmd6
```

would be rendered in a parse tree as:

```
                                 _______________|
                                /                \
               ________________|___               \
              /                    \               \
          IF__________________      \               \
         /  \                 \      \               \
test-expr1   cmd1; cmd2; cmd3  (nil)  cmd4; cmd5;     cmd6
```

Looking at the leaves:

1. test-expr1:  might fork, if it involves running a command, otherwise needn't.
2. cmd1; ... :  likely fork, unless they are internals.  One forked shell can run these sequentially
3. cmd4; cmd5:   likely fork, unless internals.  One forked shell can run these seq.
4. cmd6:        likely fork, unless internal.  One forked shell can exec this.

The IF statemnet (1, 2) is piped into (3).  (3) is piped into 4.  so, if your command was:

```
if /bin/echo You; then /bin/echo say; /bin/echo hi; fi | { cat -; echo I; echo say; echo Lo;  } | cat -;
```

you get the output:

```
You
say
hi
I
say
Lo
```

Comment: ps echo is normally a builtin, but /bin/echo isn't.

Answer (score 0):

> This was incorrect, though, as echo $$ still reports the same PID even in piped command lists.

This was correct, and your method of checking that was incorrect. From [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html):

> ($$) Expands to the process ID of the shell. In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the invoking shell, not the subshell.

So you checked that the invoking shell is the same in all subshells. It is.